# polymorphic resolution of generic parameters in Unity registerType

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am trying to do the following and failing:

```
class base {}

class derived1 : base {}

class derived2 : base {}

interface itr<t>
where t : class, base
{}

class c1: itr<derived1>
{}

class c2 : itr<derived2>
{}
```

//The following 2 registrations fail:

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<itr<base>, c1>("c1");

_unityContainer.RegisterType<itr<base>, c2>("c2");
```

The error I get is that the second parameter in the above registrations cannot be typecast into the first parameter and this registration is not valid. Any suggestions on how I can do this?
I need to do the above instead of registering with the derived1 or derived2 classes as generic parameters because while resolving I don't want to have to know the exact derived type I am resolving. I only want to work with base type methods polymorphically.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this because generics are not covariant.  That is, the type `itr<derived1>` cannot be converted to `itr<base>`, even though `derived1` can be converted to `base`.

Here's an example of why, using the framework `List<T>` class:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("Hello, World!");

// This cast will fail, because the following line would then be legal:
List<object> list2 = (List<object>)list1; 

// ints are objects, but they are not strings!
list2.Add(1);
```

So accessing `list1[1]` would return a boxed `int` in a list that was declared to contain `string`s.

Therefore, this cast is not allowed since it would break the type system.

(As a side note, in the clause `where t : class, base`, you do not need to specify `class`.  `base` itself is a reference type, so the `class` constraint is redundant.)