# casting generics

Tags: c#, generics, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [polymorphic resolution of generic parameters in Unity registerType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269279/polymorphic-resolution-of-generic-parameters-in-unity-registertype)

This is probably obvious. But can someone tell me why this is not valid code?
The compiler says it can't convert `Class1<string>` to `Class1<object>`.
Is upcasting this way not allowed with generics? If so, why not?

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Tests
    {
        public void Test()
        {            
            Class1<object> objectClass1 = new Class1<string>();
        }
    }
    class Class1<T>
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a common question, search for covariance.  Here is one thread on the topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example

Comment: Also see [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269279/polymorphic-resolution-of-generic-parameters-in-unity-registertype/4269376#4269376) for an explanation of *why* this is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

[Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

[Eric Lippert has a series of blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) on this subject.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down it addresses the question asked corectly.

Comment: @Ben: This may address the question, but it does not *answer* it. It's like asking your professor a question and them telling you that the answer is in the textbook.

Answer (score -5):

String, Int32, and so on are Struct types, while object, Person and so on are class objects for C#.
For this reason, when you create generics, you have to specify a constraint if you plan to use casting features.
So, you can use

```
public void Method<T>() where T : class
or
public void Method<T>() where T : struct
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the question.